# About name collisions in multiple inheritance

Tags: flutter, dart

Because the method names are the same, MixinB is executed and MixinA cannot be executed.

```
class Sample with MixinA , MixinB{
void sample(){
  call();
  call();
}
}

mixin MixinA{
void call(){
  print('MixinA');
}
}

mixin MixinB{
void call(){
  print('MixinB');
}
}
```

Is the only solution to this problem either changing the method names so they don't match, or using Class instead of Mixin? Is there any other solution, such as giving it a different name?

By the way, there is no relationship between `MixinA` and `MixinB`, so we do not think that `MixinB` inherits from `MixinA`.

Comment: I tried this code and no error, both call use the `call` method from `MixinB`. [DartPad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e22db4935ac3901e3c141f82cc5b603f)

Comment: very sorry. No errors occurred.
The question was about MixinA's call method not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

**It will processed from left to right.**

In this case, MixinB appears after MixinA in the with clause. Therefore, the call() method provided by MixinB will override any conflicting methods provided by MixinA. When call() is called within the sample() method, it will invoke the implementation of call() provided by **MixinB**.

```
void main(){
  Sample().sample();
}

class Sample with MixinA , MixinB{
  void sample(){
    call(); // MixinB
    call(); // MixinB
  }
}

mixin MixinA{
  void call(){
    print('MixinA');
  }
}

mixin MixinB{
  void call(){
    print('MixinB');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute the call methods of MixinA and MixinB using sample()?

Comment: You can try by giving a different name to methods, or you can try a trick like [this](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5c36462bd03fdbf305239678f8898514).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There are many ways to do this using `class`. After all, `mixin` has limited uses (it can't be helped since it is like that).